# Can't check a target for my AVD

Tags: android, eclipse

When i add a new AVD, i got the target list disabled:

[image]

I am new to Android, am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open android sdk manager and then install at least one android platform (Package) 
Installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you opened up the sdk manager and installed android?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure

1.you have android installed from sdk manager

2. You have set the correct path in Eclipse. Window--->Preferences-->Android-->SDK Location. If everything is fine. you will see the android versions in the list.